# How to make Support Vector Machine source code without using libraries in R?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, r, svm

I want to estimate *w* and *b* using loops and functions. I also want to predict new variables. I need simple scratch code to understand the mathematics behind the Support Vector Machine.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. The question is too broad, please explain your difficulty in more detail. Also it's a bad idea to try to understand the mathematics of SVM from some code, start by studying the theory and then implement it. Finally there are multiple open-source libraries that you can study, for example [sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/main/sklearn/svm).